# Adding mongodb extension to PHP-7.1.9 XAMPP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, php-7.1, lampp, php-mongodb

I have installed lampp(XAMPP) server on my ubuntu pc and now I want to add mongodb extension to it's PHP. So I tried `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongodb` and it successfully installed it. But after that, when I try to start lampp server It just pop up:

> XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a
>   32 bit compatibility library for your system

So [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/671#issuecomment-344207101) is the Github issue I was created for this.

I also tried build this extension manually for both 64-bit and 32-bit and install it(refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php)), in 32-bit case it shows another error(for more details you can refer [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/671#issuecomment-344207101)) but in 64-bit it shows same massage as above.

Note: Here is the output for `/opt/lampp/bin/php -v`

> /opt/lampp/bin/php: relocation error:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so:
>   symbol SSL_library_init, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file
>   libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue??

Comment: Much as the comment chain on the issues suggest, there appears to be something "borked" in your install of your environment. Have you tried setting up a VM from scratch? i.e Clean ubuntu install, [install XAMPP 64-bit binaries which actually do exist for the platform](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)? Because it seems something is confused about your setup, and this is likely a product of the steps you did beforehand. You might try just that and then at least list every step you did that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @NeilLunn you can get some idea of steps produced this issue by going through the: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/671#issuecomment-344207101

Comment: Read it. I'm asking you to "start from scratch" and then list everything you do. That's what is missing from the issue you posted. So if you can show us all the steps right after ubuntu install through to installing the driver and getting the same errors, then that's "reproducible" and gives us an idea where to look. Get it? Good. So show us a completely reproducible case.

Answer (score 0):

i did the same and ended up with a broken xampp installation

what i did after:

- install apache2, mysql and php
- monogodb using system pecl

now everything work for me, apparently trying to add mongodb damage the xampp installation